# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload ERROR on Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to check if a user is authenticated, then navigate them to the Homepage, and if not navigated, direct them to the Pin Screen. But I have tried and I am getting this error

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"BottomBar","params":>{"screen":"Home"}} was not handled by any navigator.
> Do you have a screen named 'BottomBar'?
> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator.

Here is how I am trying to check the authentication

```
const App = () => {
  const [onboarded, setOnboarded] = useState(false);
  const [isBiometricSupported, setIsBiometricSupported] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const compatible = await LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync();
      setIsBiometricSupported(compatible);
    })();
  });

  function onAuthenticate() {
    const auth = LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({
      promptMessage: 'Authenticate',
      fallbackLabel: 'Enter Password',
    });
    auth.then(result => {
      setIsAuthenticated(result.success);
      console.log(result);
    }
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getStorage();
  }, []);

  const getStorage = async () => {
    const onboarded = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@onboarded');
    setOnboarded(JSON.parse(onboarded));
  };

  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SFBold: require("./assets/fonts/sf-bold.ttf"),
    SFMedium: require("./assets/fonts/sf-medium.ttf"),
    SFRegular: require("./assets/fonts/sf-regular.ttf"),
    SFLight: require("./assets/fonts/sf-light.ttf"),
  });
  if (!loaded) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme} >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={onboarded ? 'BottomBar' : 'Onboarding'} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="BottomBar" component={BottomBar} />
          <Stack.Screen name="PinScreen" component={PinScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here is my PinScreen, where the user should be navigated to the Homescreen after inserting the correct Pin

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

const [pin, setPin] = useState('');
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const [isPinSet, setIsPinSet] = useState(false);

const handlePinSubmit = async () => {
    if (!isPinSet) {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@pin', pin);
            setIsPinSet(true);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            const storedPin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@pin');
            if (pin === storedPin) {
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
                navigation.navigate('BottomBar', { screen: 'Home' });
            } else {
                console.log('Incorrect PIN');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Kindly Help

Comment: Where does `isAuthenticated` come from in the first codeblock?  Just because you `setIsAuthenticated` in the PinScreen, doesn't mean the first codeblock knows about it.  I think we need more code.  Also keep in mind that setState calls are async, so even though you `setIsAuthenticated`, the next line of code to navigate may run before that state variable updates properly, so it is trying to `navigate` to a `Stack.Screen` that does not exist yet

Comment: I have updated my code indicating where isAuthenticated is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoind using useNavigation in components that act as screen. They per default receive a prop called navigation, which you may want to use to navigate, in fact.

Docs explanation
[why you should not use useNavigation hook inside screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar)

So try to change your useNavigation hook (dont use it) and use navigation prop that your pin screen receives.